# How to deal with `apt-get autoremove` in Ubuntu

Tags: apt, uninstall, aptitude

(I can list more than 20 pages with kind of similar questions/concerns. But, I could not find any solution. So, please bear with me before marking this as duplicate.)

It's been almost three weeks that I switched from Windows to Linux (Ubuntu). I have been trying to find the right tools for my applications. So, I have been trying lots of different applications in Linux. As a result, I installed/removed a lot of applications using `apt-get`.

After one of these install/remove commands, `apt-get` suggested to run `apt-get autoremove` command. I did so and then I realized that it also removed some of my desktop applications and the look of my desktop environment completely changed. As I am not expert in Linux, I ended up spending time and re-installing it!

That was when I decided to never use `apt-get autoremove` again. I, then, searched around and came across `deborphan` which was recommended for removing orphan packages. So, instead of using `apt-get autoremove`, I was using below command to get rid of unwanted packages:

```
sudo deborphan --guess-all | xargs sudo apt-get -y remove --purge
```

This was just fine till recently that after running it, Qt-Creator stopped compiling my C++ code with the error `cannot find -lGL`. It was just fine right before using `deborphan`. Luckily, I was able to fix it by re-installing `libgl1-mesa-dev` package.

So, this, unfortunately, was also the end of my trust in `deborphan`.

Now, after couple of days of using neither of `apt-get autoremove` nor `deborphan`, here is the long list of packages that `apt` suggests for removal:

```
 0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 79 to remove and 0 not upgraded.> The following packages will be REMOVED:   fonts-wine
 geany-plugins-common gir1.2-evince-3.0 gir1.2-gconf-2.0
 gir1.2-nautilus-3.0 gir1.2-poppler-0.18 libboost-atomic1.62-dev  
 libboost-atomic1.62.0 libboost-chrono1.62-dev libboost-chrono1.62.0
 libboost-context1.62-dev libboost-context1.62.0  
 libboost-coroutine1.62-dev libboost-coroutine1.62.0
 libboost-date-time1.62-dev libboost-date-time1.62.0
 libboost-exception1.62-dev   libboost-fiber1.62-dev
 libboost-fiber1.62.0 libboost-filesystem1.62-dev
 libboost-graph-parallel1.62-dev libboost-graph-parallel1.62.0  
 libboost-graph1.62-dev libboost-graph1.62.0 libboost-iostreams1.62-dev
 libboost-locale1.62-dev libboost-locale1.62.0   libboost-log1.62-dev
 libboost-log1.62.0 libboost-math1.62-dev libboost-math1.62.0
 libboost-mpi-python1.62-dev libboost-mpi-python1.62.0  
 libboost-mpi1.62-dev libboost-mpi1.62.0
 libboost-program-options1.62-dev libboost-program-options1.62.0
 libboost-python1.62-dev   libboost-python1.62.0
 libboost-random1.62-dev libboost-regex1.62-dev
 libboost-serialization1.62-dev libboost-serialization1.62.0  
 libboost-signals1.62-dev libboost-signals1.62.0
 libboost-system1.62-dev libboost-test1.62-dev libboost-test1.62.0  
 libboost-thread1.62-dev libboost-timer1.62-dev libboost-timer1.62.0
 libboost-type-erasure1.62-dev libboost-type-erasure1.62.0  
 libboost-wave1.62-dev libboost-wave1.62.0 libboost1.62-dev
 libboost1.62-tools-dev libhwloc-dev libibverbs-dev libieee1284-3:i386 
 libnuma-dev libopenmpi-dev libpython3-dev libpython3.6-dev libwine
 libwine:i386 linux-headers-4.13.0-21 linux-headers-4.13.0-21-generic  
 linux-image-4.13.0-21-generic linux-image-extra-4.13.0-21-generic
 mc-data mpi-default-dev ocl-icd-libopencl1:i386 python-glade2         
 python3-dev python3.6-dev thunderbird-locale-en wine32:i386 wine64
```

I neither have the time nor the knowledge to go through this list and find out which package I do really need and which is fine to be removed.

I also tried to mark them all as "manual" with the hope that after doing so, `apt-get autoremove` can determine which are really orphan and unwanted to be removed. I used `aptitude keep-all` and it always freezes. I found that this is a [bug](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=842707) supposed to be fixed but apparently is not.

Question: 
What is the safest approach to remove unwanted applications/libraries in Ubuntu that does not involve checking all of the packages and their dependencies one by one?

Comment: Please edit your post to include terminal text as text within code tags rather than as an image.

Comment: IMHO there is no way to avoid manually reviewing the list of packages marked for any sort of removal. IMHO apt can suggest potential packages for removal using a set of rules, but, just because a package is orphaned or marked for removal does not mean it is unecessary or not in use. My advice is to review such lists after you have removed a package and not as a part of "routine system maintenance". If in doubt, leave the package installed.

Answer (score 7):

## The rules for autoremoval are actually quite simple.

The specific answer to your question "*safest approach to remove unwanted applications/libraries in Ubuntu that does not involve checking all of the packages and their dependencies one by one*" is: Let Apt do its job. You can do that when you better understand how apt makes its decisions. For most new users, this is a normal part of the learning curve. So let's discuss Apt logic....

Apt has no idea if you are *using* a package or not. It's not psychic. It only knows each package's dependencies, and what you tell it. In order for any package to be eligible for autoremoval (orphaned), it must meet **two criteria**:

1. It must be apt-marked as `auto` (instead of `manual`)
2. No `manual` package depends --directly or indirectly-- upon the package.

There are **three complicating behaviors** that confuse users.

3. Apt remembers which packages you explicitly install and marks those packages `manual`. All other dependencies are marked `auto`.
4. The Ubuntu installer marks ALL initial packages on a fresh install `manual`. This is to keep new folks from accidentally removing huge slabs of their system.
5. Kernel packages operate slightly differently due to a bit of Ubuntu script-fu.

That's it - two rules and three special behaviors. Everything else is plain old logic.

Let's look at a couple common examples to see how those rules and behaviors apply.

**Example #1**: `sudo apt install foo libfoo`

It's fairly obvious to a human that anything called `libfoo` is probably a dependency of `foo`. But it's not obvious to apt. We explicitly told apt to install `libfoo`, so it will be marked `manual`, and won't be eligible for autoremoval.

Apt works better if we tell it `sudo apt install foo` and then let apt calculate the dependencies. `libfoo` would be (properly) marked `auto` and would be eligible for autoremoval when `foo` is removed.

**Example #2**: `sudo apt remove ubuntu-desktop`

If you build up an Ubuntu system from a [minimal image](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/MinimalCD), or if you install LAMP stacks or new Desktop Environments *after* the initial install, then Metapackages like `ubuntu-desktop` are great - the whole stack in one command. But look at it from apt's point of view: A single `manual` package and dozens (hundreds) of `auto` dependencies. The moment you uninstall the metapackage due to trying a different application...well, you get the idea.

The way out is to simply mark your key top-level applications as `manual`:

```
sudo apt install foo       // Even if foo is already installed
sudo apt-mark manual foo   // Does the same thing
sudo apt-mark auto libfoo  // Makes libfoo eligible for autoremoval someday when foo gets removed
sudo apt remove foo        // Apt will remove foo *regardless* of apt-mark
```

Remember that apt-marking simply tells apt which packages are your top-level applications ineligible for autoremoval - it does NOT protect them from human folly.

**The easy way to browse an autoremoval list** for most folks is to simply look for top-level key application packages - your email client, your web browser, your IDE, your favorite game. Look for `foo`, ignore `libfoo`.  When one does slip by and get removed, simply reinstall it - remember that telling the system to install a package marks it `manual`. **However**, your particular use case is more complicated since you compile software and use `-dev` packages. There is no magic solution for you (sorry) - you must take the time to learn which packages are important to you...just like the rest of us did.

**Caveat**: All this applies to deb packages from the Ubuntu repositories. If you add a lot of weird packages from someplace else, then there is more package housekeeping you must do. Remember that apt has no knowledge of nor control over pip, snap, flatpak, appimage software, downloaded binaries or scripts, or compiled code.

Comment: The rules may be simple but ... As the OP points out, apt and the rules it uses can not determine if a package is in use, for example, the removal of a -dev package the OP cites in his/her question as they are compiling from source code using headers from the ubuntu repositories. Personally I advise reviewing the list of packages suggested for removal, apt can make suggestions, but only the end user can determine if such suggestions make sense. When in doubt, don't remove as IMHO, apt is not so great at removing packages.

Comment: @Panther edited based upon your comments. Thank you.

Comment: @user535733 Thank you very much for your detailed answer. How about limiting the removal to packages that user explicitly installed using `apt-get install` command? This may be done by a script to generate a list of these applications and then find their dependencies and check them against list of packages that `autoremove` suggests? This will guarantee that none of the system packages are touched. Am I right?

Comment: To limit removals, @Panther's excellent advice is even easier than writing a script. If you can suggest a 'system package' that autoremove  wants to remove, perhaps we can offer more specific advice. Looking at the list you already provided, all of those look like add-ons; none look like they were included in the original install.

Comment: @NESHOM - The "problem" you are having is multifactorial . Part of the problem is no script can determine if an installed package is in use or "needed" by you, the end user. Part of the problem is in the design of the autoremove function, it is not really designed as you envision. Last, and perhaps the elephant in the room, apt is not designed to uninstall packages or revert changes. For example, removing a meta package, such as ununtu-desktop, is never simple. Other package managers / OS  (yum / dnf / arch / gentoo ) have more of the removal or reverting functions built in (not perfect).

Comment: @Panther - You mentioned "apt is not so great at removing packages". So, then what is the best approach for removing packages especially unwanted ones? You also mentioned that "... no script can determine if an installed package is in use or needed by you". Why? If a script can create a list of packages that explicitly installed using `apt-get install` + their dependencies, and then compares them against the packages that `autoremove` or `deborphan` suggests , it can come up with a list of unwanted/orphan packages that are related ONLY to the explicitly installed packages by the user. Right?

Comment: @NESHOM - It is hard to explain in the limited space here, take a look at dnf history and you will see it is easy to undo "transactions". apt does not have such features. After removal of packages sometimes you have problems such as this - https://askubuntu.com/questions/1014383/can-boot-after-autoremove-virtualbox-dependencies . Just because a package is orphaned does not mean you are not using it, best example would be -dev packages which contain headers used to compile . Scripts can not make these sorts of determinations. Try to remove ubuntu-desktop (google it)

Comment: @Panther - So is it better not to use apt for removing? If so, what is your recommendation? How do you do it? Also, if a package is orphan AND is a dependency of one of the packages installed by `apt-get install`, then removing it EVEN if it is still needed and `autoremove` doesn't know it, would cause issues ONLY in those packages and not in the system packages. Each package has dependencies specified by the developer and apt knows them (right? please correct me if wrong). Comparing this list with the `autoremove` list, the script can determine a less-harmful-to-remove list. Right?

Comment: @NESHOM AskUbuntu is a specialized Q&A site, ongoing discussion is discouraged. Comments are intended to help improve the questions and answers to help the most future readers.  If you have a specific follow-up question, please open a new Question. If you seek interactive mentoring on how to use apt effectively, then the format of our sibling support site, https://ubuntuforums.org may be more to your taste.

Comment: @user535733 - what if you don't get your answer? Should you just leave your original question unanswered and post a new one that is relatively similar? In case of this posting, I got the answer "Let Apt do it's job" where I clearly mentioned that `autoremove` made me to re-install everything. This doesn't seem to me a functional solution.

Comment: @NESHOM those are excellent questions about how AskUbuntu works - use the 'Search' box at the top of the page to find the long-written answers. If you find the first answer unsatisfying, wait for the second answer to appear.