# Can boot after autoremove VirtualBox dependencies

Tags: boot, package-management, virtualbox

I'm running Ubuntu 17.

```
$ uname -a:
Linux hellodolly 4.13.0-36-generic #40-Ubuntu SMP Feb 16 20:07:48 UTC 2018 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux.
```

I decided to switch to KVM from VirtualBox. So I first searched `dpkg -l` for `Virtualbox*` and purget it. Then the packackage manager said I still had some unnecessary packages and encouraged me to autoremove them, which I did. The programs were: `virtualbox-dkms`, `dkms`, `libvnc server`, and `libgsoap-2.8.49`.

After that I reboted and during the part of the boot where there are green `[OK]` notices, there was a: [Failed] notice which said

```
`Failed to start AppArmor intialization. See 'systemctl status apparmor.service' for details.
```

Also, the screen flashed on and off several times and then froze. After a certain time, even <kbd>CTL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>DEL</kbd> didn't work.

I can still log in from recovery mode and make changes. So, the relevant parts of that command are:

```
Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/apparmor.service; enabled; vendor preset:
Active: inactive (dead)
```

At first I tried removing the apparmor files from `/etc/init.d/`. That changed the nature of the boot error (to some minor extent), but in the end the same flashing and freezing happened. I put the file back into the `/etc/init.d/` and the original problem came back.

My guess is that there is some disrepancy between what the boot sequence expects to find, and what it sees. I'm not sure where to go about learning more about this though.

Can anyone tell me the cause of this, and how to get my system to boot again?

Comment: I am not sure what caused all this, it appears you had a problem with apparmor, although I am not sure why from the packages you listed. You then compounded the problem by removing files from /etc/init.d , can you undo that ? If not it is probably best to consider reinstalling at this point. You could try booting to recovery mode and disabling apparmor - https://help.ubuntu.com/community/AppArmor#Disable_AppArmor_framework and then try to boot see what if any additional problems you encounter.

Comment: good point. When removing it from init.d didn't fix, the problem, I put it back and the original problem came back.

Comment: I am sorry but I do not see an easy fix and it appears you have significant problems apparmor and some additional problem(s). I think it is going to be faster to reinstall than debug the current situation. As a last ditch effort you can try to reinstall ubuntu-desktop and VirtualBox see if that pulls in packages you are missing.